# SQL Join without repeated Records from one table

Tags: sql, join

Hi am using Mysql PHP combination i have 3 tables named 

1. Student(nameid,name,percent)

2. Location(locid,area,state)

3. Refer(referid,locid,nameid) for **MANY-TO-MANY** Relationship which means
A Student have many Location records as well as A Location have Many students these relation is maintained by Refer table by specifying both table ID'S(STUDENT,LOCATION) and Records of both tables should not duplicates 
**MY TABLES**
**TABLE-STUDENT**

NAMEID - NAME - PERCENT 
N1 ---- nameA   -------70
N2----- nameB   -------63
N3----- nameC   -------45
**TABLE-LOCATION**
LOCID   --AREA--    STATE
L1-------areaA  ----------P
L2------areaB   ---------   Q
L3-------areaC--------  R
**TABLE-REFER**
REFERID--   NAMEID--    LOCID
R1--------  N1------    L1
R2--------  N1------    L2
R3----------    N2------    L1
R4----------    N3------    L3
**ACTUAL OUPUT**
NAMEID--    NAME--  PERCENT --LOCID--   AREA--  STATE
    N1----- nameA-----70------L1------areaA--   ---P
    N1------nameA----70-------L2------areaB-----    Q **Duplicate STUDENT RECORD**
    N2------nameB----63-------L1-----areaA------    P
    N3------nameC----45-------L3-----areaC------    R

**Problem:**
When i try to join three tables by sql join as follows 
select * from student join refer on student.nameid=refer.nameid join location on location.locid=refer.locid
It display records which  includes duplicate from student(if student records connected to more than one record from location) but i need only unique student record which have many location records like 

**NAMEID-- NAME--  PERCENT--   LOCID-- AREA--  STATE**
N1----- nameA   -----70-------  L1--------  areaA----   P
--------------------------------L2--------  areaB----   Q ***NULLfor repeated records in Student***
N2----- nameB--------63-------- L1--------  areaA-----  P
N3------nameC--------45---------L3--------  areaC-----  R
 
 **or** 
 

**NAMEID-- NAME--  PERCENT--   LOCID-- AREA--  STATE---LOCID2--    AREA2-- STATE2**
N1---------nameA--- -----70------   L1-------areaA----P------------L2----------areaB------Q ***Location should be combined with Student***
N2--------  nameB----------63------ L1----- areaA------ P
N3-------nameC-----------45-------L3------  areaC----   R
 

  **Plz suggest me the way to achieve this by SQL statement or PHP code because i have to make a report from this Data like


**REPORT:
 
NAME: nameA

PERCENT:70

AREA1:areaA

AREA2:areaB

STATE1:P

STATE2:Q

-----------------------------

NAME: nameA

PERCENT:63

AREA1:areaA
a
STATE1:P**



 THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: Thanks for trying to format your question properly. A little tip: It is even better to use the code block for queries and table definitions. It is a icon in the editor. You should try it. You can mark existing text and click it. +1 from me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a work for the application itself :

```
$results = array();
while ($data = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
  if (!isset($results[$data->NAME]))
    $results[$data->NAME] = array('percent' => $data->PERCENT, 'areas' => array(), 'states' => array());
  $results[$data->NAME]['areas'][] = $data->AREA;
  $results[$data->NAME]['states'][] = $data->STATE;
}

// parse $results into your report...
```

Comment: If you're familiar with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, you can use $data['NAME'] instead of $data->NAME. It gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about presentation, and not about relational operations on SQL tables.

When you do the JOINs in the manner you show, that's two relational joins, and the result contains the duplication you want to suppress.  Relational operations deal with the data as a set, not as a series.  Note that you are not getting two rows that duplicate each other.  You could get that if table REFER had dups in it.  You could suppress exact dups by using SELECT DISTINCT.

The best way to blank out the parts of a result row that duplicate the previous row is to do this in the report writer.